# Hide not first child from every class parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here with my html and jQuery code

```
<div class="tabbed">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div> <!-- want to show then hide rest -->
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
</div>
<div class="tabbed">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div> <!-- want to show then hide rest -->
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
</div>
<div class="tabbed">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div> <!-- want to show then hide rest -->
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="tabs"></div>
    <h2>Title</h2> 
    <div class="tabs"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".tabbed > .tabs:not(:first)").hide();
```

Comment: what is the question that you are actually asking here?

Comment: thanks for editing - much clearer now.

Comment: Hi @Chris added more info to make more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer to match your new question code:

```
$(".tabbed").find('.tabs:not(:first)').hide();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PVz4W/1/)

---

The above may not look "right" as one would assume that `:first` would return only 1 element, but it has the same effect as this more verbose and CPU-consuming form:

```
$(".tabbed").each(function() {
    $(this).find('.tabs:not(:first)').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PVz4W/2/)

I assume the [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method does the iteration internally before executing the selector for each element in the set of matched elements, so the latter code snippet is unnecessary. However, you can use the more verbose and bulletproof form if you ever encounter problems when upgrading or downgrading jQuery in the future.